# How markdown cant identify the output

Tags: r-markdown

I ma trying to run following code and it keeping running into an error. I did work on previous occasion, but now it doesn't seem to work.

```yaml
---
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: format.docx
---
```

> Error: object 'output' not found

Comment: Try checking the file "format.docx" is in the same directory as the file being knitted.

Comment: It is in the same directory